# How much lateral acceleration during cornering is needed to flip a car?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration

I'm doing my IB HL Math Exploration, where I use a bit of physics. Say I have a car with mass m, center of gravity at height h, and width of 2b, and I am turning a corner, how much centrifugal acceleration is needed for the inner wheels of the car to leave the ground?

I'm trying to solve [this](http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Mechanics/Circular%20motion/text/Cars_cornering/index.html) question using this website. However, as the IB Physics course does not cover torque :(, I am unable to understand the working out.

I understand the working until this line:

> Taking moments about the centre of gravity :

What does it mean by taking moments?

> $R_2b = Fh$ and so $F = \frac{R_2b}{h} = \frac{mgb}{h}$

How are these equations derived?

The car in my exploration is not necessarily travelling in a circular path, but in paths including those modeled by the function $f(x) = x^2$. However, I do have the acceleration of the car. Therefore, can I simply use Newton's Second Law $F = ma$ and the derived $F=\frac{mgb}{h}$, and equate $a = \frac{gb}{h}$?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Look at this figure and take the sum of the torques about point B.

Comment: How would I find the torques of the three forces shown in the diagram? Do I have to resolve them into vectors that are perpendicular to the like from B to the center of gravity? Do I need to consider the horizontal frictional force not shown as well?

Comment: For a static equilibrium $\sum _{\tau }=\dfrac {mv^{2}}{r}\cdot h-mg\cdot b+F\cdot 2b=0$